# wcf service unable to parse datetime from javascript running in ie

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, wcf, internet-explorer

I have a WCF service with a method defined like so:

```
<WebGet(), OperationContract()>
    Public Function GetScene(cameraId As Integer, time As Date, bufferSize As Integer) As Scene
```

and javascript that looks like this:

```
time = new Date("04/09/2013 23:59")
$.getJSON('../Services/CameraViewerService.svc/GetPreviousScene', 'cameraId=' + _cameraId + '&time=' + time.toUTCString() + '&bufferSize=20', function () {...});
```

in chrome and firefox the date in the query string ends up looking like this:

`Tue, 09 Apr 2013 23:59:00 GMT`

and the WCF service consumes it just fine, but when I use internet explorer 9 the date in the query string looks like this:

`Tue, 9 Apr 2013 23:59:00 UTC`

and the WCF service throws an exception:

`The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 26.`

What is the best way to get this to work for all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

This should hopefully parse OK as it's one of the recognised standard date and time [formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

In IE8 and [earlier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) `toISOString()` is not supported but the Mozilla documentation from my first link has an example shim which you can use if there is not support for the function.